# how to make marquee text dynamically

Tags: android, flashlight

In xml file inside a relative layout I have taken a textview. I provided the text,  font size, text color in the java file. but still i am not able to get the marquee text. How should i do it.
Thanks in advance

MainActivity.java file

```
public class MarqueeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marquee);

        // got the data from another activity 
        String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("Text");
        float fontSize = getIntent().getFloatExtra("FontSize", 64.0f);
        int textColor  = Color.alpha(getIntent().getIntExtra("TextColor",0xff0000ff));
        int bgColor = Color.alpha(getIntent().getIntExtra("BGCOLOR",0xff0000ff));

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_marquee);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // created text view
        TextView marqueeText = new TextView(this);
        marqueeText.setText(str);
        marqueeText.setTextSize(fontSize);
        marqueeText.setTextColor(Color.alpha(textColor));
        marqueeText.setBackgroundColor(Color.alpha(bgColor));
        marqueeText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE,Typeface.BOLD);
        marqueeText.setSelected(true);
        marqueeText.setSingleLine(true);
        marqueeText.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        marqueeText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);

        relativeLayout.addView(marqueeText,params);
    }
}
```

Please correct the above code to get the marquee text

Answer (score 0):

you want the people do it for you, thats wrong.

You can use:
 Strings in XML
 Arrays in XML

Create a random function and select a random element from the list, array, etc.